# Is it fine to have multiple bundle ids for a single flutter app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have flutter app that includes firebase, but I have multiple bundle ids for this app.

So is it ok that firebase has a bundle id, if I want to publish app to the store with another bundle id?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add secondary bundle id in Firebase console to the same project.

After that get new `Google-Services.plist`, because api keys in there are tied up to bundle id, so some Firebase features may not work or break unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the new bundle ID in to the Firebase console to ensure functionality of Firebase in the app.

And also a point of caution if you decide to make the android version too, then make sure when you upload the app to Google Play store, don't distribute the other versions with a different signing key. That will get you banned.
I've faced this so you have to be careful when signing and assigning bundle ids to apps.